# A sum of powers of binomials

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

For $n$ and $k$ non-negative integers, let $$F(n,k) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^k.$$ For example, $F(n,0)=n+1$, $F(n,1)=2^n$ and $F(n,2)=\binom{2n}{n}$. Does there exist a general formula for $F(n,k)$?

Comment: as an experiment, you can compute several values of $F(n,3)$ and check the resulting integer sequence with the database at oeis.org ...

Comment: It can be proven using the [WZ algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf-Zeilberger_pair) that the sum of the cubes of binomial coefficients does not possess a closed form. See [A = B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html) for more details.

Comment: @Lucian, thanks - I did not know about this WZ Algorithm.